# Choosing URL to use arcpy.SignIntoPortal_server() correctly?

Tags: arcpy, feature-service, arcgis-portal

I'm trying to write some code to automate updating a feature service. I found some code online that uses,

```
arcpy.SignIntoPortal_service(username,password,portal)
```

to sign into the portal service.

I looked up the documentation of the code [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/server-toolbox/sign-in-to-portal.htm). The documentation states that the portal parameter doesn't actually do anything and that,

> "[the] default value is URL for the ArcGIS portal currently chosen by
>   the user in Desktop Administrator."

Should I add the rest services url to the list in the desktop administrator or should I add the admin url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the url displayed in your browser when you go to your portal's homepage (excluding `/home`). It should look like `https://myportal.company.com/portal` or something similar.

Be aware there is an existing limitation (noted on that page) that sometimes requires physical interaction with the sign-in dialog (preventing long-running unattended scripts).

Comment: Where is the limitation discussed? I read the documentation a few times and couldn't find it. I asked another question about an error I ran into. Could you look at it?

Comment: There's a gray box of text in the Summary section indicating this is a legacy feature. "Signing in to ArcGIS Online or Portal for ArcGIS through ArcGIS for Desktop has changed in the ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 release. You may receive Warning 1561 when executing this tool. If you receive this message you cannot use the Sign In To Portal tool to authenticate, but must sign in to ArcGIS Online or Portal by clicking File > Sign In."